# Stopping while loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

can anybody help me to stopp this infity loop?
**This loop shoud stopp if an input is a String.**
All digits should be added to a list.
Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    addDigitsToList();

}

public static void addDigitsToList() {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int input = 0;

    while (true) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

            input = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            list.add(input);

        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            for (Integer integer : list) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the infinity loop than use the keyword
break;
on which condition you want to stop it. You told us to stop when the input is a string than you should update your code-

Comment: I need something like if (input == String) than break.
But how can I compare int with String?

Comment: So use if(input == String){break;}

Comment: And if my answer helped you so mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Right after the for loop add this :

```
   break;
```